# Openlayers Plugin

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin, openlayers-2

I just downloaded QGIS 2.8 and tried to download the Openlayers pLugin but it isn't installing and I don't know how  to get the open source data in my map. How do I download Openlayers Plugin for Mac and how do I then install it into the QGIS program?

Comment: Welcome Susi. Please provide more detail, such as: link to the instructions are you following. At what step did the instructions fail? How you do you know the plugin didn't install (ie. what message did you get?).